# Impact or applications of introducing attention in deep networks modelling multi-agent systems

Tags: neural-networks, attention, game-theory

I have been reading quite a lot about the research progress in the domain of self attention-based neural networks that were introduced by Google Inc. in their paper titled ["Attention is all you need"](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/7181-attention-is-all-you-need.pdf).

The concept of introducing attention to neural networks in order to free ourselves from a strict context vector being really unique on one hand and moreover using the same concept to model sequences without recurrent neural networks as introduced in the paper is extremely elegant.

I have been trying to figure out so has to how this concept of attention would aid deep networks that model multi-agent systems in which game-theoretic factors come into play for the network to learn.

I was looking for some direction or a toy example/explanation or even possible previous research done to try to test these concepts together.

P.S - I'm just tinkering with some ideas hoping to build something experimental.